# How can I get the Finder to show metadata?

Tags: finder, metadata

I am running MacOS Mojave 10.14.6 on an iMac. Sometime last July, the Finder started hiding the metadata of downloaded photos. Its behavior varied for a while, but now it seems to have settled down to the following.

I open a pic -- e.g., https://fs3.fotoload.ru/f/0220/1580572066/e367aaa0e2.jpg -- in a browser window and drag it to the Desktop. The Finder's Get Info shows this:

[image]

I open a Column-view Finder window for the Desktop, with all the Image Preview Options enabled, and select the pic. I get this:

[image]

I drag the pic to a folder, which is also in Column view. The metadata appears briefly (< 1 sec), then changes to this:

[image]

Get Info shows only this:

[image]

That's also what I get if I drag the pic directly from the browser to the destination folder.

If I open the pic in Preview, it shows the metadata. What can I do to get the Finder to act like it used to and always show the metadata? I have installed no Finder extensions or photo management software.

Answer (score 1):

Under the View menu, there is an item "Preview Options". This allows you to specify what data will be shown in the Preview pane.

This item (and the various parameters it contains) may only be available when you the Preview panel is showing and you have an image file selected.

These are the defaults:

[image]

Comment: I always run with all those options enabled. The Finder simply refuses to report the contents of those fields, even when they contain data.

Comment: FWIW, if I check those boxes, I see the relevant information in the Preview panel of a Finder window, even for your test tiger photo. I'm on Mojave 10.14.7. I presume you've rebooted since it started? Have you installed an software that might interfere with the Finder, e.g. Finder extensions such as DropBox, or some other photo file management system? Are you using a specific View Style (ICon, List, Column)? Please add your answers to the question. Thanks.

Comment: Mojave 10.14.7? When I ask about Software Updates, the only option I am shown is Catalina 10.15.7.

Comment: Ah: No, you're right: it's only 14.6.